# How to automatically input a value in a text box based on another and vice versa?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a couple of simple inputs that using $_POST update results in a database.

```
<input type='text' name='1' value='$1'>
<input type='text' name='2' value='$2'>
```

Now the thing is, what ever I enter into input 1, I would like the remainder of 10 in input 2. Meaning the total value of both the inputs will always be 10.

So

```
Input 1 = 1 then input 2 will be = 9
```

or

```
Input 1 = 4 then input 2 will be = 6
```

and so on.

But I also want it to work the other way if I enter the value in input 2, input 1 populates as above.

```
Input 2 = 4 then input 1 will be = 6 etc.
```

I'm assuming this is done with Java script, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

You're right: you have to use javascript for that.

```js
//when input 1 changes...
document.getElementById('1').onchange = function(){
  //...get its value...
  var val_1 = document.getElementById('1').value;
  //...calculate the corresponding value for input 2...
  var val_2 = 10 - parseInt(val_1);
  //...and set it
  document.getElementById('2').value = val_2;
}
//do the same for input 2
document.getElementById('2').onchange = function(){
  var val_2 = document.getElementById('2').value;
  var val_1 = 10 - parseInt(val_2);
  document.getElementById('1').value = val_1;
}
```

```html
<input type='number' name='1' id='1' value='1' min='0' max='10'>
<input type='number' name='2' id='2' value='9' min='0' max='10'>
```

### Please also keep in mind that...

If you're using HTML5, the best input type for numbers is "number" instead of "text". This allows you to set a minimum and maximum number that can be set.

### A better solution

When a number is inserted without using the arrows, the other input will change only when the user clicks out of the input they've just edited. If you want to avoid that, you can use this (better) solution.

```js
function changeInput2(){
  var val_1 = document.getElementById('1').value;
  var val_2 = 10 - parseInt(val_1);
  document.getElementById('2').value = val_2;
}
var input_1 = document.getElementById('1');
input_1.onchange = function(){
  changeInput2();
}
input_1.onkeyup = function(){
  changeInput2();
}
var input_2 = document.getElementById('2');
function changeInput1(){
  var val_2 = document.getElementById('2').value;
  var val_1 = 10 - parseInt(val_2);
  document.getElementById('1').value = val_1;
}
input_2.onchange = function(){
  changeInput1();
}
input_2.onkeyup = function(){
  changeInput1();  
}
```

```html
<input type='number' name='1' id='1' value='1' min='0' max='10'>
<input type='number' name='2' id='2' value='9' min='0' max='10'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you asked.
Here it is

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYrGLw

HTML

```
<label for="1">Input 1</label>
<input type="text" class="totalinput" id="1" value=""/><br>
<label for="2">Input 2</label>
<input type="text" class="totalinput" id="2" value=""/>
```

jquery

```
$('input.totalinput').on('keyup', function(){
   var newVal = $(this).val();
   var rem = 10-newVal;

   var other = $(this).siblings('input.totalinput');
   other.val(rem);
})
```

Comment: Including jquery may slow down the loading of the page and is not necessary in this case

Comment: The question is tagged with jQuery

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones you're right, I didn't notice about that, but the OP wrote in their question "I'm assuming this is done with Javascript"... Anyway, I'm leaving my answer as it is, so they have both solutions (one with jquery and one with vanilla js) available

Comment: By saying "this is done with Javascript" (when tagged with jQuery, especially from a beginner) I think it's safe to assume they don't necessarily know the difference between JS/jQuery, but if they have jQuery loaded then they have the option to use either/both.  So agreed, either this or your solution would work for them.